# PayPal MECL inappropriate UX message issues on iOS and likely Android/other mobile platforms

Tags: ios, paypal, integration, user-experience

We’re implementing the PayPal MECL library in a client’s app but we’re experiencing some poor user experience that we don’t seem to be able to change. 
When the PayPal experience is complete, PayPal show a “Please wait while we transfer you to the business site...” message. Obviously this is an iOS app not a “business site”...

The flow functions by dismissing the web view on completion of the PayPal experience by listening for new URL requests within the UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This issue seems to be that PayPal update their web view with the message via editing the DOM (JS or some such) which does not create a new web request and therefor no shouldStartLoadWithRequest fired. Note: A new request is made after a second or so when redirected but that’s too late, the inappropriate copy has been presented to the user.

Has anyone working with MECL on iOS or Android managed to alter this copy/experience either via the [SetExpressCheckout](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout) server call or configuration of the [MECL URL get params](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPECOnMobileDevices)?I ’ve been unable to find a resolution on this so far but will post a solution if we find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated as we don’t seem to be able to find a solution in PayPals documentation...

**NOTE:** Also we have a similar UX issue when pressing the cancel button on the PayPal web view that causes a redirect, but with a similar bad piece of copy presented before hand “Cancel this purchase and return to the seller’s website?”. This is worded as a confirmation dialogue but there are no buttons presented and it redirects anyway. Mad UX. Again if anyone knows a solution to either if these please post.

[image: "Please wait while we transfer you to the business site..." image]

[image: "Cancel this purchase and return to the seller’s website?" image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the response from our friendly PayPal support team (paid retainer contract).

*"Hi *_*,

Unfortunately there really aren’t any customisable options on the MECL web views. They are essentially provided as is.

Thanks,
*_*"*

Looks like this is a closed box. Bad UX it is or another payment solution. I’m accepting this as the answer as it looks likely that nothing can be done here sadly.